# Trouble with validation testing and updategrams

Tags: xml, validation, sql-server-2012

So I'm trying to validate an XML message against a schema that exists on the hard disk locally that makes use of microsofts update grams using XML notepad and XML Copy Editor and have run into a bit of a snag.  Namely, I'm getting this error...

Error at line 1, column 61: no declaration found for element 'ROOT' when trying to validate the following code...

```
<ROOT xmlns:updg="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-updategram">
<updg:sync mapping-schema="C:\Dev\Backup\vb script\4bogdang\mm2Messages_1_11_SQL.xsd">
    <updg:before></updg:before>
    <updg:after> 
        <customTextRsp>
            <action>complete</action>
            <source>{07518bdd-226b-41a7-a662-a66000954e26}</source>
            <deviceType>MM2BIN</deviceType>
            <customText>
            <language>English</language>
            <index>1</index>
            <buttonText1></buttonText1>
            <buttonText2></buttonText2>
            <feeDisclaimer1></feeDisclaimer1>
            <feeDisclaimer2></feeDisclaimer2>
            <receiptFeeText1></receiptFeeText1>
            <receiptFeeText2></receiptFeeText2>
            <receiptPayout1></receiptPayout1>
            <receiptPayout2></receiptPayout2>
            <receiptTitle1></receiptTitle1>
            <receiptTitle2></receiptTitle2>
            <receiptTitle3></receiptTitle3>
            <receiptTitle4></receiptTitle4>
            <receiptFooter1></receiptFooter1>
            <receiptFooter2></receiptFooter2>
            <receiptFooter3></receiptFooter3>
            <receiptFooter4></receiptFooter4>
            <reportTitle1></reportTitle1>
            <reportTitle2></reportTitle2>
            <reportTitle3></reportTitle3>
            <reportTitle4></reportTitle4>
            <reportFooter1></reportFooter1>
            <reportFooter2></reportFooter2>
            <reportFooter3></reportFooter3>
            <reportFooter4></reportFooter4>
            <screenText1a></screenText1a>
            <screenText1b></screenText1b>
            <screenText2></screenText2>
            <pleaseTakeReceipt></pleaseTakeReceipt>
            <disclaimer></disclaimer>
            <disclmBtnText></disclmBtnText>
            <agreeBtnText></agreeBtnText>
            </customText>
        </customTextRsp>
    </updg:after>
  </updg:sync>
</ROOT>
```

The problem is happening at this line as indicated by the error...

```
<ROOT xmlns:updg="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-updategram">
```

I checked the way it's written based on the samples found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172697.aspx) and the urn appears correct.  For XML Copy Editor do I need to include this somehow in the catalog file?  If so, what is the correct way to enter it in the catalog file? (I'm a bit new to using this tool, unfortunately.)

I suppose the second question I have is that is it possible the environment I'm using for testing is missing files?  I have Microsoft SQL Server 2014 installed so I'd assume that updategram support is in place given it was added years ago according to my searches.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.  I needed to change the root to specify an XMLSchema-Instance for the XML validation testing.